# Anybody have a more efficient way to write this php function?

Tags: php

I was just practicing and wanted to see if there was a more robust way to write this? Should I use a for loop?

```
<?php
function recursion($number){
   if ($number === 0){
        break;
  }
    else {
        $subtracted_number = $number-1;
        echo $subtracted_number;
        recursion($subtracted_number);

    }
 }



recursion(9);
?>

//output is 876543210
```

Comment: This question should be posted on [codereview.se], if anywhere.

Comment: usually recursion is the most efficient way to do something, in fact, many functions of an operating system are built in recursion, for example the file system and the way it traverses it, pure recursion.

Comment: `while (--$number) echo $number;` ?

Comment: "This question should be posted on Code Review, if anywhere. –  Mike W 29 mins ago"   - why "if anywhere?" sorry I m new and thought stackoverflow was used for questions like this as well. ie. optimizing coding practices and practice in general - is it to beginnerish? Thanks. Any websites you would suggest for this type of post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can do it in a simple `for` loop you won't need your `recursion` here

```
function countdown($num)
{
  for($i=$num-1; $i>0; $i--)
  {
    if($i !=0)
      echo $i;
  }
}
```

use as:

```
countdown(9);//echoes 87654321
```

Comment: double reduction, will not work

Comment: @IlyaBursov - hahha my mistake, edited :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursion($number){
   $number--;
   if ($number > 0){
        echo $number;
        recursion($number);
   }

}
```

Just for fun http://codepad.org/4S4BcofG

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursion($number) {
 while ($number > 1) {
  $number--;
  echo $number;
 }
}
```